# Quadratic Residue problem

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Suppose I have two primes $p,q$ such that $pq=n$. How can I solve the congruence equation $x^2 \equiv 1 (\mod n)$?
Is this done by Chinese Remainder Theorem on $x \equiv 1 (\mod p)$ and $x \equiv 1 (\mod q)$?
Help!
Do any other alternative approach exist?

Comment: No, by CRT on $x\equiv1\pmod p$ and $x\equiv-1\pmod q$.

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 \equiv 1 (\mod n) \Rightarrow x^2 \equiv 1 (\mod p) \quad$ and $\quad x^2 \equiv 1 (\mod q)$.

So solve $x^2 \equiv 1 (\mod p)$ - say there are $a$ solutions mod $p$. Then solve $x^2 \equiv 1 (\mod q)$ - say there are $b$ solutions mod $q$. Each of the $ab$ pairs from these solutions sets gives you one solution to $x^2 \equiv 1 (\mod n)$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Unless $p=2$ or $q=2$ you will have $a=b=2$ and so 4 solutions mod $n$.

Comment: How can I solve the congruence $x^2 \equiv 1 (\mod p)$ ? Given $p$

Comment: Factorising $x^2-1 \equiv 0 (\mod p)$ gives two distinct solutions (or just one is $p=2$), and as the congruence classes mod $p$ are a field there can be at most 2 distinct solutions.